# Find occurrences of dates in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have the following simplified table:

```
Create table Services (
  ServiceID   int        not null,
  Created     Datetime   null,
  Authorised  DateTime   null,
  Closed      Datetime   null)
```

How can I group the DateTime fields as per the month to count out how many services were created, authorised or closed in a particular month?

This is the result I am looking for:

```
Month Year   Created   Authorised   Closed
 08    2016     10         12         3
 09    2016     12          4         9
 10    2016      7          9         6
...
...
```

I am not able to figure out the GroupBy statement to achieve this, even though it seems simple enough. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You'd select the created count per month, the authorised count per month and the closed count per month separately and fully outer-join the three.

Unfortunately SQL-Server doesn't feature standard SQL's `JOIN table USING (columns)`, so a full outer join, especially with more than two tables involved, looks clumsy.

```
select 
  coalesce(closed.mon, created.mon, authorised.mon) as [Month],
  coalesce(closed.yr, created.yr, authorised.yr) as [Year],
  created.cnt as [Created],
  created.cnt as [Authorised],
  authorised.cnt as [Closed]
from
(
  select month(created) as mon, year(created) as yr, count(*) as cnt
  from services
  group by month(created), year(created)
) created
full outer join
(
  select month(authorised) as mon, year(authorised) as yr, count(*) as cnt
  from services
  group by month(authorised), year(authorised)
) authorised on authorised.mon = created.mon and authorised.yr = created.yr
full outer join
(
  select month(closed) as mon, year(closed) as yr, count(*) as cnt
  from services
  group by month(closed), year(closed)
) closed on  closed.mon = coalesce(created.mon, authorised.mon)
         and closed.yr = coalesce(authorised.yr, created.yr);
```

Comment: Wow. That's a handful. I will need to see if this can be modified as my real table actually has a lot more date/time columns. It doesn't look like a good idea to make 8 full outer joins!

Comment: Don't worry too much. The DBMS is made to do exactly such things. It may use hash joins here, which should be fast. And remember that it's only few records that need be joined, because the data is already aggregated.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTECR (Y, M) AS (
    SELECT 
        DATEPART(Year, Created), 
        DATEPART(Month, Created)
    FROM [Services]
),
CTEA (Y, M) AS (
    SELECT 
        DATEPART(Year, Authorised), 
        DATEPART(Month, Authorised)
    FROM [Services]
),
CTECL (Y, M) AS (
    SELECT 
        DATEPART(Year, Closed), 
        DATEPART(Month, Closed)
    FROM [Services]
)
SELECT M, Y, ISNULL(Created, 0), ISNULL(Authorised, 0), ISNULL(Closed, 0) FROM (
SELECT M, Y, COUNT(*) AS 'Cnt', 'Created' AS 'Evt' FROM CTECR GROUP BY M, Y
UNION ALL 
SELECT M, Y, COUNT(*), 'Authorised' FROM CTEA GROUP BY M, Y
UNION ALL 
SELECT M, Y, COUNT(*), 'Closed' FROM CTECL GROUP BY M, Y
) A
PIVOT (
    SUM(Cnt) 
    FOR Evt IN (Created, Authorised, Closed)
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I have a more date/time columns in the real table along with other Grouping columns. I will try to see if this is workable for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I try using grouping sets.
Sample data -

```
declare @temp table (
    ServiceID       int         not null,
    Created         Datetime    null,
    Authorised      DateTime    null,
    Closed          Datetime    null
)

insert into @temp
select 1, '2016-08-03', '2016-07-03', '2016-02-03' union
select 2, '2016-10-03', '2016-04-03', '2016-08-03' union
select 3, '2016-04-03', '2016-02-03', '2016-12-03' union
select 4, '2016-04-03', '2016-01-03', '2016-10-03'
```

Actual code -

```
;with grouped as (
select  created     = format(created, 'yyyyMM'),
        authorised  = format(authorised, 'yyyyMM'),
        closed      = format(closed, 'yyyyMM'),
        count_val   = count(*)
from @temp
group by grouping sets(
            format(created, 'yyyyMM'),
            format(authorised, 'yyyyMM'),
            format(closed, 'yyyyMM'))
)
,combined as(
select [Month]=right(created,2),[year]=left(created,4), created=count_val, authorised, closed
from grouped
where created is not null
union all
select [Month]=right(authorised,2),[year]=left(authorised,4), created, authorised=count_val, closed
from grouped
where authorised is not null
union all
select [Month]=right(closed,2),[year]=left(closed,4), created, authorised, closed=count_val
from grouped
where closed is not null
)
select [Month],[year],created=sum(created),authroised=sum(authorised),closed=sum(closed)
from combined
group by [Month],[year]
```